# Fundamental group of a manifold of dimension 4

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, fundamental-groups

I want to find a manifold of dimension 4 which fundamental group is $F_{\alpha}$ (the free group on $\alpha$ generators).
Since the fundamental group of the connected sum is the free group of the fundamental groups I think it just be enough to find a 4th dimensional manifold which fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}$.

I don't know if $D^{3}\times S^{1}$ is a 4th dimensional manifold but it would work since $D^{3}$ (the ball ofdimension 3) is contractible.

Comment: You can just use $S^3$, you only need simple connectedness. Also I think your claim about the connected sum requires the dimension to be at least $3$?

Comment: Yes. The dimension is needed tu be at least 3. So $S^{3}\times S^{1}$ is a manifold of dimension 4? this is the part that I don't know how to explain.

Comment: @Yeipi $D^3\times S^1$ is indeed a 4-manifold. It's homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, but this is irrelevant to the problem. In general, since the fundamental group behaves nicely with respect to cartesian product, we just need any simply connected 3-manifold $W^3$ and then $\pi_1(W^3\times S^1)\cong\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Yeipi: do you know that the product of two manifolds is a manifold?

Comment: Actually, I don't... @QiaochuYuan

Comment: I think you should start by learning basics of manifolds, you are simply not ready for the question you are asking.

Comment: Yeah, I think so to but my course was suposed to be "a basic course in topology" but the teacher wanted to evaluate this kind of stuff